what's means V is model of zfc?
I thought that set of formulas S has a model iff there is an interpretation satisfying that all the formula in S make true.
so I understand zfc's model is a kind of assignment that make all the zfc's axioms true.
but in explanation about inaccessible cardinal in wiki(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal at this link, in the section with the titled "Models and consistency"), V is zfc's model, but I thought that V is closure of powers-set operation starting with empty set. so it is not a kind of assignment.
so why these kind of collection of set is called by model of zfc? it seems that i have some confusion of definition of something.

Please link the "explanation in wiki" that you are looking at.

But anyway, the usual explanation is that one always make a background assumption that ZFC is consistent, that a model therefore exists, and that a model is chosen with the various assignments specified in the usual manner. $V$ is then defined as a submodel of the chosen model (using the scheme that you outlined, i.e. the closure of power-set operation starting from the empty set).

@LeeMosher I don't understand why collection like V can be called model, model contain assignment( i.e.kind of function) but V is just class.

@LeeMosher is it the reason just V has all the set that each of zfc's axioms talk about?

I was just following the convention of that wikipedia link, which says If $V$ is a standard model of ZFC.... So in that setting, $V$ is assumed to be a model to start with, hence it is a set.

There are a couple of subtleties here. (For clarity I'm going to distinguish the actual elementhood relation $\in$ from a canonical symbol representing it $\varepsilon$)
First of all, and I think this is the issue you're asking about here, when $\Gamma$ is a set of sentences in the language $\{\varepsilon\}$ we often write "$A$ is a model of $\Gamma$" as an abbreviation for "The $\{\varepsilon\}$-structure with underlying set $A$ which interprets $\varepsilon$ as $\in$ (restricted to $A$) is a model of $\Gamma$," or more snappily $$(A;\varepsilon\mapsto(\in\cap A^2))\models\Gamma.$$ A pure set is not the same as an $\{\varepsilon\}$-structure, but (at least in the usual set-theoretic ontology where everything is a set) it does have a natural expansion to an $\{\varepsilon\}$-structure. This is analogous to how we often refer to e.g. a metric space by its underlying set alone, when a metric is clear from context.
A more subtle issue is about the size of the structure involved. If $\alpha$ is an ordinal, then (adopting the above shorthand) the statement "$V_\alpha$ is a model of ZFC" may not be true but it at least is grammatically correct. The statement "$V$ is a model of ZFC," however, is not even grammatically correct! This is because models by definition have to be sets, not proper classes, equipped with additional structure. (This may feel superficial at first, but it's actually a serious point; see e.g. the discussions here, here, or elsewhere on this site.)
